# Java - If I have an object which is an object array of another object can I still use it as an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a card game in Java and I have a Card object, a Deck (an array of card objects) and a Hand (Also an array of card objects).
I am using a method to draw cards in Deck which I have attached below:

```
public Card [] drawCard(Deck Deck , Hand Hand, int x, int y) {
    Hand[x] = Deck[y];
    return Hand;
}
```

In my main class I use the above method to draw cards from the Deck to the Hand.

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++) {
    Deck.drawCard(Deck, PlayerHand, i, i);
}
for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++) {
    x = 2;
    Deck.drawCard(Deck, PlayerHand, i, x);
    x++;
}

String PlayerCard1 = PlayerHand[0];
String PlayerCard2 = PlayerHand[1];
String DealerCard1 = DealerHand[0];
String DealerCard2 = DealerHand[1];
```

However, I am receiving the error message *"[Java] The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Hand
Hand PlayerHand - Main.main(String[])"*.

I don't understand how to fix this error so can someone please explain to me where it's wrong?

I have attached my deck class and hand class below.  Please feel free to give me feedback on them as well.

Hand class:

```
public class Hand {


  Hand(){
      Card [] Hand = new Card [9];
  }
}
```

Deck class:

```
public class Deck {


//enter code here

  Card [] Deck = new Card[52];

  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      for(int x = 0; x < 13; x++) {
        int cardNID = (i+1)*(x+1);
        deck[cardNID] = new Card(i+1,x+1);
      }
  }


}


public void ShuffleDeck() {
    for (int i = Deck.length - 1 ; i > 0; i = i - 1) {
      int j = (int)(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      int temp = myList[i]; 
      myList[i] = myList[j]; 
      myList[j] = temp;
    }
}



public Card [] drawCard(Deck Deck , Hand Hand, int x, int y) {
    Hand[x] = Deck[y];
    return Hand;
}
}
```

This is my first question so I apologize if it isn't "good".

Comment: Just a tip: You should name variables or instances to start with a _lowercase_ character (`deck`, `hand`) so as not to be confused with the class name (`Deck`, `Hand`). Here's a link to the (archived) [Oracle coding conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/codeconventions-135099.html) (there are other more comprehensive coding conventions out there).

Comment: @GinoMempin Thanks for the tips.  I will use information from the link you posted in the future.

Comment: In addition to what @GinoMempin said, method names also start with lowercase.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to make those changes by editing the question now. It should increase your chances of someone helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function:

```
public Card [] drawCard(Deck Deck , Hand Hand, int x, int y) {
Hand[x] = Deck[y];
return Hand;
```

You're passing objects not arrays. Then inside that functions you're trying to use them like they're arrays.

Comment: So do you think that I should just make an array called Deck and Hand inside the main class?